# Linux Mint 18 with Cinnamon Session Save and Restore

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, session, persistence

Is there any way to save the position / workspace and possibly state of all of my open programs so that when I restart I can restore everything to exactly where it was before without having to reopen and reposition everything?

Comment: That would be really nice to have. I'm not aware of how to get that exact feature, but as a work-around "suspend to disk" should achieve a similar thing: computer can be shutdown completely (as the "memory image" is saved to disk), and after "resume" the last state should be restored. Just doesn't help if you really have to reboot, e.g. due to kernel updates.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how :

1. Execute `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
2. Run `dconf-editor`
3. On the left panel : Open `org` > `gnome` and click on `gnome-session`
4. Check `auto-save-session` on the right side of the config window

Comment: Can you expand on what this actually achieves? Does this mean I can type shutdown -h now and resume my session later or is it just protection against crashes? What actually happens? Is state periodically saved to disk?

Comment: You may have to install ``dconf-editor`` instead of ``dconf-tools``

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much as above **Except** org > cinnamon > cinnamon-session.
Accept defaults. I put the delay time at 20 do give applications time to close gracefully.
Works for me

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1414765

Answer (score 2):

Just in case that someones find this (like me) while searching for a solution to change the Low Battery Action Percentages in Linux Mint 18.3 I tried this solution (dconf-editor) using Linux Mint 18.3 and the Power Management ignores the values set in DConf for some reason.

I had to edit this file: */etc/UPower/UPower.conf*, concretely these 3 lines:

```
PercentageLow=25
PercentageCritical=15
PercentageAction=13
```

In order to make it work as I wanted. I also changed:

```
UsePercentageForPolicy=true
```

because I don't like the "timed actions" default behaviour

Good luck!