# Mint: how to save a session

Tags: linux-mint

How to keep opened the apps (term, xed, webbrowser etc.) with a content after the mint (19.3) restart? It seems that there is the dconf-editor that allows for saving gnome and cinamon session but it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for moving the question here. It wasn't relevant to SE.DSP.

Comment: found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314749/linux-mint-18-with-cinnamon-session-save-and-restore